# Is it okay to list the projects I've worked on for a web agency for my portfolio website?

Tags: career-development, portfolio, web

I'm currently planning my portfolio website and I'm wondering if it's cool to list out (+ screenshots of the website + details of the processes that went into developing it) a few agency projects that are mainly developed by my self and is created for public viewing?

A FYI, I've signed a contract which says that anything created by me is the property of xxx business.

If I'm not allowed, would it be ok to make the project listing page password-protected so that only the interviewers can view it?

Comment: You should ask permission of the owners, but expect the answer to be no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a **public portfolio** you can list your own work.. either personal projects or freelance work that you've done for your own clients.

It's not cool to display a list work that you've done while working for another company, as the company owns those projects and your work, not you.

Even if your company does give you permission, the client hasn't. It may be possible to get permission from both, but you risk causing some awkwardness between the company and client.

For a **private portfolio** that you only share with potential employers.. Providing there isn't some kind of specific NDA, then basically this is what everyone does.

I'm not a lawyer, so I don't know if you technically need permission for a private portfolio however, in reality everyone does it anyway.

(by private portfolio I am talking about a portfolio used to show an employer as an example of your work. If you used this private portfolio to get your own clients that would not be good)

Answer (score 1):

You should ask permission of the owners, but expect the answer to be no as they are their products. So building them was done by their staff members and would be advertised as such if advertised. They would be trying to get more work for the company. Quite possibly the products do not even get advertised as such and all rights belong to the customer who would not want your old companies name associated with them or your own.

> If I'm not allowed, would it be ok to make the project listing page password-protected so that only the interviewers can view it?

No if the company refuses you should not attempt to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a draft that only reveals your previous activities, qualities and achievements, but leaves out any reference to your (previous) employer/customer or any other individuals or specific companies, or references that could be easily reduced to that. Thus you will have something in hand to show and get agreement on.

On top of that you should ask to be allowed to mention that company as a reference, since that is often also prohibited by the NDA. It might help if you can find an incentive that would motivate that company to agree

Get it in writing!
A simple, "oh okay." won't do..

However, do expect a negative answer.
Chances are, you're gonna get one.
My ex did her dissertation on IBM.
That story didn't go very far.

Whatever you do, do not risk an NDA court case.
If its off limits, that's just what it is.
You did most literally sign up for that.